Plotting 3x3 Linear System
I am trying to plot the following linear system ($3\times 3$) in different ways. My question is what wrong have I done to my last code?
eq1 = 2 x - y + w == -5;
eq2 = y + 3*w == 7;
eq3 = w == 2;

(*Use ContourPlot3D to visualize*)
ContourPlot3D[{2 x - y + w == -5, y + 3*w == 7, w == 2}, {x, -10, 
  10}, {y, -10, 10}, {w, -10, 10}, PlotLegends -> "Expressions"]


ParametricPlot3D[{{x, y, -5 - 2 x + y}, {x, y, (7 - y)/3}, {x, y, 
   2}}, {x, -10, 10}, {y, -10, 10}, AxesLabel -> {"X", "Y", "Z"}, 
 BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}]


Plot3D[{-5 - 2 x + y, (7/3) - (1/3) y, 2}, {x, -4, 4}, {y, -4, 4}, 
 PlotLegends -> "
Expressions"]



Just due to display/plot/scaling difference. This gets to look almost the same by playing with plot range and Mesh options.
eq1 = 2  x - y + w == -5;
eq2 = y + 3*w == 7;
eq3 = w == 2;
eqs = {eq1, eq2, eq3}

ContourPlot3D[eqs, {x, -10, 10}, {y, -10, 10}, {w, -10, 10}, 
 PlotLegends -> "Expressions", BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}, 
 PlotRange -> {{-4, 4}, {-4, 4}, Automatic}, Mesh -> 10]


ParametricPlot3D[{{x, y, -5 - 2  x + y}, {x, y, (7 - y)/3}, {x, y, 
   2}}, {x, -10, 10}, {y, -10, 10}, AxesLabel -> {"X", "Y", "Z"}, 
 BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}, PlotRange -> {{-4, 4}, {-4, 4}, Automatic}, 
 Mesh -> 20]

Plot3D[{-5 - 2  x + y, (7/3) - (1/3)  y, 2}, {x, -4, 4}, {y, -4, 4}, 
 PlotLegends -> "Expressions", BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}, 
 PlotRange -> {{-4, 4}, {-4, 4}, Automatic}, Mesh -> 8]




There might be other options to tweak. The point is, it is just a view/display issue. Each command uses has its own settings how to display the 3D final image.

Oh!!! Thank you! I didn't know that!

There is nothing wrong with your code as far as I can tell.
You may think there is something wrong because the outputs look different.
I believe this is because the orientation and scale of the three plots are not the same.
Make the scale and orientation the same and they look essentially identical. Do this by setting the PlotRange, BoxRatio and ViewPort the same.
v = Options[Plot3D, ViewPoint][[1, 2]]

ContourPlot3D[
 {
  2  x - y + w == -5,
  y + 3*w == 7,
  w == 2
  },
 {x, -10, 10},
 {y, -10, 10},
 {w, -10, 10},
 PlotLegends -> "Expressions",
 BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1},
 ViewPoint -> v,
 PlotRange -> {{-10, 10}, {-10, 10}, {-10, 10}}
 ]


ParametricPlot3D[
 {
  {x, y, -5 - 2  x + y},
  {x, y, (7 - y)/3},
  {x, y, 2}
  },
 {x, -10, 10},
 {y, -10, 10},
 AxesLabel -> {"X", "Y", "Z"},
 BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1},
 ViewPoint -> v,
 PlotRange -> {{-10, 10}, {-10, 10}, {-10, 10}}
 ]


Plot3D[
 {
  -5 - 2  x + y,
  (7/3) - (1/3)  y,
  2
  },
 {x, -10, 10},
 {y, -10, 10},
 PlotLegends -> "Expressions",
 ViewPoint -> Dynamic[v],
 PlotRange -> {{-10, 10}, {-10, 10}, {-10, 10}},
 BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}
 ]


